# How to implement kerberos authentication with login/password?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-security, kerberos

We have a standalone kerberos AS (not AD, it's a particular system), so no one user's workstation knows about that, but some users have their credentials (login + password, no keytab).

**Problem**: we need a spring boot service (SERVICE) and frontend application where a user can type credentials, get SPNEGO token from SERVICE and continue to work with it further, web-browser mustn't know about that authentication.

**Pre-requisites**: spring-boot, java 14, SERVICE has keytab (http/service@REALM), user has login+password

**How we see a solution**:

1. Frontend send login + password via SSL to SERVER;
2. SERVER does kinit (or something else?) to KDC, gets TGT/TGS, sessions keys;
3. SERVER responds to frontend with SPNEGO token.

**Question**: is it good way to solve the problem? If yes, how can we get an SPNEGO token for pair login+password in java?

Answer (score 0):

Asking for user's password is definitely not the safe approach. Most of the users will be reluctant to provide their credentials to the backend server.

Based on what you have written, I assume you have to do some stuff on user's behalf (in the backend) and pass user's kerberos ticket to other kerberized services.
Better way will be to -

1. Put your application in Kerberos authentication mode. This way, your
   backend server will always receive user's kerberos token (only once during first time authentication to your application).
2. Enable **Kerberos Constrained Delegation** from AD Settings. Doing this, you
   can delegate user's kerberos token to other Kerberized Applications.
3. You can save the user's kerberos token in your app session, and use
   it whenever you want.

This is much safer approach. Only challenge is how you renew the token you already have. But usually kerberos tokens are valid for 8hours, so I don't see major concern.